# Tikz matrix node unwanted vskip in first column

Tags: tikz-matrix

I have a strange vertical skip in a `tikz` `matrix node` within the first column I can not figure out how to eliminate:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=1.75cm,yshift=3pt,
table/.style={
    matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,align=left,draw=black,font=\scriptsize, 
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex},
    nodes in empty cells,
    column 1/.style={text width=0.46\textwidth},
    column 2/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 3/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 4/.style={text width=0.30\textwidth},
    column 5/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 6/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth}
    }]
\node[matrix,table,anchor=north west] (first) at (0.5,4)
{
    Endogenes Konstrukt & $ R^2 $ & $ Q^2 $ & Exogene(s) Konstrukt(e) & $f^2$ & $VIF$ \\ 
    
    (KB) & 0,34 &  0,30 & (GA) & 0,53  & - \\ 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid CR between lines in your matrix. Or at least, use `%` for it not to be taken care.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=1.75cm,yshift=3pt,
table/.style={
    matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,align=left,draw=black,font=\scriptsize, 
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex},
    nodes in empty cells,
    column 1/.style={text width=0.46\textwidth},
    column 2/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 3/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 4/.style={text width=0.30\textwidth},
    column 5/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth},
    column 6/.style={text width=0.05\textwidth}
    }]
\node[matrix,table,anchor=north west] (first) at (0.5,4)
{
    Endogenes Konstrukt & $ R^2 $ & $ Q^2 $ & Exogene(s) Konstrukt(e) & $f^2$ & $VIF$ \\ 
   (KB) & 0,34 &  0,30 & (GA) & 0,53  & - \\ 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: vertical skip]

Answer (score 2):

I would modified your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
table/.style={
    matrix of nodes, 
    nodes={minimum height=1.5em, text depth=0.5ex, text width=0.05\textwidth,
           inner xsep=0.005\textwidth, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
           draw, font=\scriptsize, align=left},
    nodes in empty cells,
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    column 1/.style={nodes={text width=0.44\textwidth}},
    column 4/.style={nodes={text width=0.30\textwidth}},
    }]
\matrix[table] (first)
{
Endogenes Konstrukt & $R^2$ & $Q^2$ & Exogene(s) Konstrukt(e)   & $f^2$ & $VIF$ \\
(KB)                & 0,34  &  0,30 & (GA)                      & 0,53  & --    \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Observe differences in:

- nodes style, which contain also width of narrower columns
- defined matrix inner and outer separation (set to zero)
- column styles (defined are only two)
- removed are all shifts and nodes positions settings (which  haven't any influence on matrix position)

[image]

Red lines in above image are added that matrix position in page is simpler to see.

Comment: Thx Zarko for your refinements. Especially, I find your adjustment to the exact '\textwidth' of the whole table very helpfull! Didn't think of merely setting inner sep to a specified fraction of the textwidth to precisely account for it in overall width calculation.

Comment: @kilsen, looking your problem I wonder why you use TikZ picture to write simple table. For example with `tabularx` with combination of `X`, `p{...}` and `l` columns this table is far easier to write.

Comment: I know, but it is for a ```beamer``` presentation, where I apply ```\onslide``` to partially uncover parts (e.g., columns) of the table. Something I cannot accomplish within a ```tabularx``` environment, as far as I know.